# Setting up multithreading python 3

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script which takes a list of input files and runs a cmd on these files. There is around 6,000 files in the list on average. (Varies by batch). This cmd based program takes around 1-2 minutes to complete on average per input file, so at the end of the day its around several days to process the whole list.

I was looking to use multi-threading to  split the list between several of my processors so the list can be processed in tandem and ultimately faster!

The input again being a list of files, and the output is written to the same directory as the input file but as inputx_output.csv

I can't seem to get multithreading working. This is the current code segment without multithreading. Every time I look at some multithreading references it does not seem to adapt well to my code.

This is a segment, does not contain all needed references / inputs to run individually.

```
import shutil as sh
Input_File ='c:/Users/James_Mann1/Desktop/TestBench'

import os
try:
    os.chdir(Input_File)
except:
    catch = 1
try:
    sh.rmtree("Cas-Out")
except:
    catch = 1
try:
    os.mkdir("Cas-Out")
except:
    catch = 1 
#print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("Cas-OffInput")
path = os.getcwd()
Input_Casoff = os.listdir(path)
src = Input_File + "/cas-offinder.exe"
dst = Input_File + "/Cas-OffInput/cas-offinder.exe"
sh.copyfile(src, dst)
for value in Input_Casoff:
    subprocess.call("cas-offinder " + value + " G0 " + " " + value + "out.txt")
    #os.system("cas-offinder " + value + " G0 " + " " + value + "out.txt")
```

I'm unsure of where to start? I can't seem to find a good reference to write this. All i'm trying to do is take list entries and run the cmd on them in tandem, so the process is done faster. The output is generated by the cmd so nothing needs to be captured.

Edit, I was able to solve the initial issue. Posted below... Now I would like to return a count, which tells me how many I have left.

```
import os
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import shutil as sh
import time
#%%
import shutil as sh
Input_File ='c:/Users/James_Mann1/Desktop/TestBench'

import os
try:
    os.chdir(Input_File)
except:
    catch = 1
try:
    sh.rmtree("Cas-Out")
except:
    catch = 1
try:
    os.mkdir("Cas-Out")
except:
    catch = 1
#print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("Cas-OffInput")
path = os.getcwd()
Input_Casoff = os.listdir(path)
src = Input_File + "/cas-offinder.exe"
dst = Input_File + "/Cas-OffInput/cas-offinder.exe"
sh.copyfile(src, dst)

Task_Count = len(Input_Casoff)

from multiprocessing import Pool

def Cas_off(x):
    os.system("cas-offinder " + x + " G0 " + " " + x + "out.txt")
    #print(x)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(8) as p:
        print(p.map(Cas_off, Input_Casoff))
```

Any suggestions on implementing a method to get remaining entries?
So

x/4000 completed or working on x/4000.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you conceivably write a function that just handles whatever processing is performed on each file? If so, then you could look at `multiprocessing.Pool` for this kind of task, where you would first have to create a list of the filenames before calling the `map` function.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? It sounds like you might need a tutorial or guide. See [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, using a bare `except` like that is and practice, and you seem to be mixing multiple naming conventions (it's best to just stick to the `lower_case_with_underscores` style for variable and function names, unless there is a good reason not to do so).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), the python version of MPI (the Message Passing Interface) that enables you to do parallel computing. MPI is quite a big library and enables you to run programs on multiple processors and even to make communications between those processors.

On MAC I installed it using brew:

```
brew install open-mpi
```

You can then install mpi4py using pip:

```
pip3 install mpi4py
```

Then the structure of your code should look like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD # MPI communicator
size = comm.Get_size() # Number of processors
rank = comm.Get_rank() # Rank of the processor

# Input and output file names
nb_files = 10
input_files = [f'input_file_{i}.txt' for i in range(nb_files)]
output_files = [f'output_file_{i}.txt' for i in range(nb_files)]

# Loop on all files to process
for i in range(len(input_files)):
    # The current processor will process only files at indexes
    # equal to his rank modulo the total number of processors
    # else it will skip the file.
    if (i%size==rank):
        # Here processor rank must:
        # - read file input_files[i]
        # - process the data
        # - write file output_files[i]
        print(f'CPU{rank} transforms "{input_files[i]}" into "{output_files[i]}".') # dummy code
```

You may be able to execute the code with the command (replace 4 by the desired number of CPUs and script.py by the name of your python program file):

```
mpiexec -n 4 python3 script.py
```

Output:

```
% mpiexec -n 4 python3 script.py
CPU3 transforms "input_file_3.txt" into "output_file_3.txt".
CPU3 transforms "input_file_7.txt" into "output_file_7.txt".
CPU1 transforms "input_file_1.txt" into "output_file_1.txt".
CPU1 transforms "input_file_5.txt" into "output_file_5.txt".
CPU1 transforms "input_file_9.txt" into "output_file_9.txt".
CPU0 transforms "input_file_0.txt" into "output_file_0.txt".
CPU0 transforms "input_file_4.txt" into "output_file_4.txt".
CPU0 transforms "input_file_8.txt" into "output_file_8.txt".
CPU2 transforms "input_file_2.txt" into "output_file_2.txt".
CPU2 transforms "input_file_6.txt" into "output_file_6.txt".
```

Be careful to avoid multiple processors working on the same files to avoid conflicts (all file names should be different). Again MPI is a very big library and with it you can imagine adding communications (every minutes for instance) to reduce between all processors the number of files done for instance.

Hope this helps.